# Facebook Style on Hover menu with Dynamic Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to develop a Facebook styled onHover menu. Upon hover over the "person" icon I should get a list of updates from different people. This is a different  called peopleList that has to come up on hover over.

1) The contents of the peopleList div is dynamic, updates can be from anybody, so a CSS alone option is ruled out. Is that conclusion correct?

2) I want the look and feel to be like this. The hovered div should come on top of the person icon like a comic text
 [image]

Comment: try this http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/mashable-floating-effect-example-with-jquery/ you need to customize your look and feel but functionality should work

Comment: use jQuery [`tipsy`](http://www.jqueryplugins.com/plugin/165/) plugin

Comment: Thanks, but that doesnt solve my problem. My problem is: I have a "person" icon with a number depicting the number of feed updates on him. When I hover over, I would like to see the people who are actually responsible for those updates. Please see the image attached